# React Native native module - transform string to hexadecimal

Tags: java, android, react-native

I need to pass string in shape of "0000000000000000" from RN to Java and transform it into hex in shape of {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, thing is that my knowledge of Java is ultra basic and eventho I successfully pass it to native module, I don't really know how to convert it inside java function. Can anyone help with that?

```
 private byte[] parseStrToHex(String str) {
      // found something like that but doesn't really work
      return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string of zeros in the format "0000000000000000" to a byte array in the format {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00} in Java, you can use the following code:

```
private byte[] parseStrToHex(String str) {
    byte[] result = new byte[str.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        String byteString = str.substring(i * 2, (i * 2) + 2);
        result[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(byteString, 16);
    }
    return result;
}
```